# How can i find path from installed software?1

Tags: path, twilio

[I am unable to set a path for twilio APIs, The API is already installed in my laptop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rxaZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have installed the Twilio Python helper library, however it does not make available an executable on your command line.

You need to write a Python program and import objects from the Twilio library. Check out these [getting started with Twilio in Python tutorials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python) for more details.